# Large almost abelian subgroups of permutation groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $m<n$. Let $t_{m,n}$ be the largest cardinality of a subgroup $G\subseteq S_{n}$ such that if $A\subseteq\{1,...,n\}$ and $|A|=m$, then the subgroup
$\{f\in G:f|_{A}=\text{Id}_{A}\}$ of $G$ is abelian. What are some good estimates for the cardinality $t_{m,n}$? I would also like to see examples of groups that witness good lower bounds for $t_{m,n}$. This question has been solved when $m=0$ with $t_{0,n}\approx 3^{n/3}$ (see [Burns and Goldsmith](http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/21/1/70.extract)).

Comment: Should the subgroup description have $f\in G$ instead of $f\in S_n$?

Comment: Arturo Magidin. Yes. Thanks for pointing that out. The typo has been corrected.